# @@Identity return same value on each insert

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, identity

I have a stored procedure where which insert an statement and returns @@Identity.

This @@ Identity returns always 1.   When removed the @@Idnetity to Identity_Scope it returns the correct expected value, which was always incremented by 1.  so this is good.  but the question is.   Why @@ Identity columns is returning 1.

i checked and removed all the trigger and checked all the function but have no idea why i am getting 1 with @@Identity. Seems like there is a table that is being truncated and then a value is being inserted.

Any clue guys why @@Identity is returning 1 all the time.  Is there server settings that is doing something?

Comment: Show your code. Probably you use `@@identity` in wrong way

Comment: Id recommend you also to use SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Comment: Silly question: does that table you're inserting data into even have a `IDENTITY` column??

Comment: The page on [SCOPE_IDENTITY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190315.aspx) explains the differences between the different functions. Why expect us to regurgitate them?

Comment: I am not asking for scope_Identity vs @@Identity.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that:

- The @@identity function returns the last identity created in the **same
  session**.
- The scope_identity() function returns the last identity
  created in the same session and the same scope.
- The ident_current(Name) returns the last identity created for a specific
  table or view in any session.

So please send us your code for better assistance. You **may** use @@Identity in a wrong way.